# Select row twice with one column modification

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, union

I have table and sql (running on Oracle):

T (it's just an example, the table is huge)

```
a  b  c
-------
1  4  7
2  5  5
3  6  8
```

sql:

```
SELECT a, b, c
FROM t

union all

SELECT 'R',b,c
FROM t
WHERE b = c AND (condition to another tables, etc)
```

It returns:

```
1  4  7
2  5  5
3  6  8
R  5  5
```

Is it possible to avoid UNION here (and don't add JOIN)? In other words - is it possible to optimize the query to avoid Oracle look into table T twice?

Comment: what means "avoid UNION" ? What is the desired output?

Comment: Aim is to reduce DB load. Actually, the table is huge and I want to avoid scan it twice. Join isn't an option here.

Comment: Desired output - the same (in question after words 'It returns')

Comment: What does `condition to another tables, etc` mean?

Comment: If your query is (pseudo-code)  "Select name, condition from Fruit UNION select name, condition from fruit where condition = 'unripe'" your resultset is the entire set plus a subset. There is no way to get both parts of the resultset without scanning the entire set a second time to retrieve the subset from it.  The full table will either be on disk or in a table-expression within your query, but either way, those tuples will have to be scanned again to apply the limiting condition (and then set your 'R' flag) for the subset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will read your table once.
The join is done with an auxiliary table which contains only two values(of course this in in memory - no I/O)

```
with t as(
  select '1' a,  '4' b,  '7' c from dual union all
  select '2',  '5',  '5' from dual union all
  select '3',  '6',  '8' from dual
)
select decode(aux.col,1,t.a,'R'), t.b, t.c 
from t
join (select '1' col from dual union all select '2' from dual) aux
on (aux.col='1' or t.b=t.c);
```

The query does not depend on '1' and '2'. It can be:

```
select decode(aux.col, 'bla', t.a,'R'), t.b, t.c 
from t
join (select 'bla' col from dual union all select 'otherbla' from dual) aux
on (aux.col='bla' or t.b=t.c);
```

**UPDATE**: Also, if number of b=c records is small, you can speed up your actual query creating an index:

```
 create index fbi on t (b-c);
```

and then replace in your query `WHERE b = c`  with `WHERE b - c = 0`

**UPDATE2** Just to get the ideea on how these queries are executed:

```
create table t(a varchar2(10), b varchar2(10), c varchar2(10));

insert into t 
select mod(dbms_random.random(),1000),
  mod(dbms_random.random(),1000),
  mod(dbms_random.random(),1000)
from dual
connect by level < 1000000;

exec DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS('DEV','T');

--1
SELECT a, b, c
FROM t;
---------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)|
---------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |      |   999K|    11M|   700   (3)|
|   1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| T    |   999K|    11M|   700   (3)|
---------------------------------------------------------------

--2
SELECT a, b, c
FROM t
union all
SELECT 'R',b,c
FROM t
WHERE b = c;
----------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation          | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)|
----------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |      |  1009K|    11M|  1426  (53)|
|   1 |  UNION-ALL         |      |       |       |            |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| T    |   999K|    11M|   700   (3)|
|   3 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| T    | 10000 |    97K|   726   (7)|
---------------------------------------------------------------- 


--3
select decode(aux.col, 'bla', t.a,'R'), t.b, t.c 
from t
join (select 'bla' col from dual union all select 'otherbla' from dual) aux
on (aux.col='bla' or t.b=t.c);


----------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation          | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)|
----------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |      | 20990 |   368K|  1402   (3)|
|   1 |  NESTED LOOPS      |      | 20990 |   368K|  1402   (3)|
|   2 |   VIEW             |      |     2 |    12 |     4   (0)|
|   3 |    UNION-ALL       |      |       |       |            |
|   4 |     FAST DUAL      |      |     1 |       |     2   (0)|
|   5 |     FAST DUAL      |      |     1 |       |     2   (0)|
|   6 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| T    | 10495 |   122K|   699   (3)|
----------------------------------------------------------------
--if the leading table is dual, can be used an /*+ordered*/ hint 
--after select clause


--4
create index fbi on t (b-c);
SELECT a, b, c
FROM t
union all
SELECT 'R',b,c
FROM t
WHERE b - c = 0;
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                    | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)|
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT             |      |  1009K|    11M|  1384  (51)|
|   1 |  UNION-ALL                   |      |       |       |            |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL          | T    |   999K|    11M|   700   (3)|
|   3 |   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| T    | 10000 |   117K|   683   (1)|
|   4 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN          | FBI  |  4000 |       |     3   (0)|
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Keep in mind that Oracle does not know to predict well on or join clauses like in 3, so better you force a desired execution path. You should test to choose between 2 and 3 and 4(with the back of the cost of the index).

Comment: 1,2,3..etc are real data numbers. I don't know these numbers before executing an sql.

Comment: You don't need to hardcode anything. The aux table is a soup. You can write it as is.

Comment: This works perfectly for me. I'll look at the ex plan an tune somehow, but I believe it's the option.

Comment: How do you know `this is in memory -- no I/O`?  The OP said the table was 'huge'. You're scanning the full set twice in any case, once to get the full set, and then to get the subset based on a condition, assigning the 'R' flag to rows in the subset where b=c. So it is not possible `to avoid Oracle look into table T twice`. Those tuples ARE being evaluated a second time. Also, he wasn't selecting constants but column-values: OP said `I don't know these numbers before executing an sql`.

Comment: @Tim Oh, no, the `dual union dual` is in memory, not the table t :)

Comment: A full table scan is "hidden" in `create index fbi on t (b-c);` :-) You are "pre-processing" the table.

Comment: @Tim That's not the downside of the index. You make a full scan and sort to create the index and then select from table many times. The downside of the index is that inserts and updates are much more slower, as I specified in the answer - there is a cost.